# Why can I not navigate to another page from FlatList component in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I'm not sure what's wrong here, as far as I can tell I am doing this correctly as it has worked everywhere else in my app. The only difference is that I'm trying to do this from a FlatList component. What is wrong with this? I've also tried putting {navigation} in renderMyItem instead of FLToyCard brackets, didn't work either. Error I'm getting is:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

import Toy from './Database'
import ToyCard from './ToyCard'

const FLToyCard = ({navigation}) => {
    
    const headerComp = () => {
        return(
            <View style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 25, padding: 10}}>All Toys For Sale</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    const renderMyItem = ({item}) => {
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <ToyCard 
                name={item.name}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                desc={item.desc}
                seller={item.seller}
                onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SlugProduct')}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                data={Toy}
                renderItem={renderMyItem}
                keyExtractor={(item)=>item.id}
                numColumns={2}
                ListHeaderComponent={headerComp}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default FLToyCard
```

This is my App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


import SlugProduct from './Screens/SlugProduct';

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login' >
             // list of other pages
             <Stack.Screen name="SlugProduct" component={SlugProduct} />
             <Stack.Screen name='ViewToys' component={ViewToys}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

EDIT: heres the ViewToys page that FLToyCard is being input into. I've tried adding the onPress into both Views and FLToyCard but got the same error each time.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

import FLToyCard from '../Components/FlatListCards'

const ViewToys = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffce20', height: '100%'}}>
      <View>
        <FLToyCard />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewToys
```

Comment: You will only get navigation props in those screen which you have added into your navigation Stack. Did you add FLToyCard into the navigation ?

Comment: @Alpha FLToyCard is just a component, its being used in a page called 'ViewToys' which I have included in the navigation stack. Edit: tried including FLToyCard anyway just in case, still had the same problem.

Comment: From screen ViewToys are you passing navigation props ? Please add ViewToys code as well

Comment: @Alpha have edited the post and included the ViewToys code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your not passing `navigation props` from screen **ViewToys** into component **FLToyCard**.

Try this

In ViewToys Screen:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

import FLToyCard from '../Components/FlatListCards'

const ViewToys = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffce20', height: '100%'}}>
      <View>
        <FLToyCard navigation={navigation}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewToys
```

Answer (score 1):

change this  `<FLToyCard />` to this  `<FLToyCard navigation={navigation} />`
and you are all done.

you are getting undefined in navigation in FLToyCard component that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

This error come when we do not put these mention in a page
 `import { NavigationContainer,useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';` 
 `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';` 
So I think put above in every page once your problem will solve,